# How to validate SSL certificate chain in ruby with net/http

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, verification

How can I verify the certificates of a site like https://processing.ukash.com/ in ruby with net/http?

```
https = Net::HTTP.new('processing.ukash.com', 443)
https.use_ssl = true
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Works so far, but how do I verify that it's the right cert now? I saved the certificate from within firefox, but the resulting .pem file has many certificates in it and net/http doesn't seem to like it.

Answer (score 25):

From my code snippets collection:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# How to:
# =======
# Use Ruby's net/https library, to verify a SSL certificate.
# ==========================================================
# - Without verification the following code will lead to:
# warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
#
# #------------------begin example-----------------------------
# require 'net/http'
# require 'net/https'
# require 'uri'
# 
# url = URI.parse 'https://myname:mypass@mail.google.com/'
# http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
# http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == 'https')
# request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
# request.basic_auth url.user, url.password
# response = http.request(request)
# #-------------------end example------------------------------
# 
#  To verify the ssl cert cosider adapting the following.
# Status: Untested
# =======
#
# References:
# ===========
# [1] http://mimori.org/%7Eh/tdiary/20080301.html#p03
# [2] http://redcorundum.blogspot.com/2008/03/ssl-certificates-and-nethttps.html
#
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

RootCA = '/etc/ssl/certs'

url = URI.parse 'https://myname:mypass@mail.google.com/'
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == 'https')
if (File.directory?(RootCA) && http.use_ssl?)
  http.ca_path = RootCA
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  http.verify_depth = 5
else
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE 
end
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
request.basic_auth url.user, url.password
response = http.request(request)
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: I asked the paste to stick forever, but dunno.  anyhow, link:  http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1460391     could easily be me. I haven't really looked into it yet.

Comment: executes now :)  when I pp the response I get #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>     however, I kinda forget what the point was.  hmm. maybe the question is a bit dissapointing.  ok, well, it's interesting and executes.  plus one!

Comment: I think the point is in devops settings you need to write executable spec's that not only describe what the infrastructure has/is - but also verifies that it is in fact operational - hence the need to verify a SSL certificate. HTH

Comment: problem with the sample is it gives no output so you have no idea if it worked. i was getting no output and assumed it was working but in reality it was just disabling the verification because i'd set `RootCA` to a file so the `File.directory?` test was false.

Comment: @drewish I am not sure I follow.  When you say "I was getting no output" do you mean `response.nil?` returned true? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness and for my future me, this is a small gem I made out of this: https://github.com/jarthod/ssl-test